# List options from a join query MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Please see image below for code and output.

The vcoptionids column has two voptionid.

How do i make it list the other option value, which is the color?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wdfbpkk0q8lwbqw/Fullscreen%20capture%2018052012%20110530%20AM.bmp.jpg

Comment: Please enter the code / output into the question text directly, to preserve it if that link expires.

Comment: would love to, only i don't know how to make it readable. the query i can, but the output i can't.

Comment: Looking at the screenshot, you have two values in the column you mentioned, separated by a comma. I assume those are IDs of a colour, stored elsewhere? Where are the colour values stored?

Comment: @jason3w see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: @DanJ Hey Dan. vcoptionids refers to the isc_product_variation_options table. currently it returns the two values associated with the product, but lists one set of the two AS voptionid and vname etc. but how to get it return the second set of options? Thanks again

Comment: Well, that's gonna be tough, which is why storing multiple foreign keys in a single column is a bad idea... I don't know the appropriate MySQL functions off-hand, but you'll need to join to the `isc_product_variation_options` table twice, using the substring of `vcoptionids` left of the comma as the join key in one case, and the substring to the right of the comma in the other (and the whitespace after the comma will need to be stripped out). Ugly. And unable to take advantage of indexes.